# I can't get any vpn to work

Tags: vpn

I am not too familiar with Linux and even less so with setting up VPN's but I have tried a lot of Open VPN software like proton VPN and Printunl and I can't get any of them to work. I have also just tried to use Nord VPN and that wasn't working either. So I don't know if it is something wrong with all the software or if there is something with my system that isn't letting anything to work or I am doing something wrong with all of them.

I have also tried using browser VPN like HOXX and Setup VPN and even the built-in Opera VPN which all work reliably on all my other non-Linux systems.

Edit: 
When I installed NordVPN I followed the instructions on the website. When I do

```
nordvpn connect
```

I get:

```
Connecting to United States #4077 (us4077.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! Failed to connect to United States #4077 (us4077.nordvpn.com).
Connecting to United States #2983 (us2983.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! Failed to connect to United States #2983 (us2983.nordvpn.com).
Connecting to United States #3360 (us3360.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! Failed to connect to United States #3360 (us3360.nordvpn.com).
It's not you, it's us. We're having trouble reaching our servers. If the issue persists, please contact our customer support.
```

It is similar to all of the other VPN's where it tries to connect and then fail. If there is a way to try to connect in some sort of debug mode please let me know so I can give more information.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? Can you provide any output from openvpn?

Comment: maybe proxy issue, at work I cannot use a vpn either because the relevant ports are filtered.

Comment: @loopis jones  Are you using an internet connection at work, school, or someplace else where you don't control the connection, or is this on a home internet which you yourself pay for? Please click [edit] and respond in the question.

Comment: I am using it at school

Comment: as you are new to linux you may not know how to install nord vpn here is a link on how to do so I recommend you try following the command line instruction at the link provided (step 2 and onward) then post any errors from the term you run into here (note download the .deb file .rpm won't work on Ubuntu) https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-and-Linux-Mint.htm

Comment: That is the link I used to install. Check my edit for the errors I got.

Comment: NordVPN is not friendly with Firewalls or any restrictions that might be an obsticle for other VPNs as well. You have to turn off the firewall to let it full access but if you don't have access to network as it's a school network that's an issue.

Comment: The browser VPN (extension) what you wrote that's a different thing as it covers only browser activity but not system activity.